# How to generate payload for below JSON structure and wrapper class

Tags: apex, callout

**JSON File for upload**

[image: JSON File for upload]

JSON for file upload

```
{
    "files": [
            {
                "name": "my file.txt",
                "data": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZmlsZQ==",
                "doctype": "pdf",
                "index":[
                        {
                            "name": "my text index name",
                            "value": "text value"  
                        },
                        {    "name": "my number index name",
                             "value": 1234
                        }
                ]
            }
    ]
}
```

```
public class mObject{
    public String tkn{get;set;}

    public List<Files> files{get;set;}
    public class Index {
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String value{get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Files {
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String data{get;set;}
        public String doctype{get;set;}
        public List<Index> index{get;set;}
    }
    
}
```

Comment: make an instance of your wrapper class. Set field values, serialize and set it as a request body.

Comment: started with to set values for 1 record but struggling with make it dynamic.Here is my code.Guess need to use map and set for dynamic payload  `mObject dfObj = new mObject();
mObject.Index i = new mObject.Index();
mObject.Files f = new mObject.Files();
f.name = myfile.name;
system.debug('BLOB** '+myfile.body);
f.data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(myfile.body);
f.doctype = 'pdf';
i.name='SFDC ID';
i.value ='1234';
List<mObject.Index> iLst = new List<mObject.Index>();
iLst.add(i);
f.index = iLst;
List<mObject.Files> fLst = new List<mObject.Files>();
fLst.add(f);
dfObj.files = fLst;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate the wrapper, fill values, and serialize.

```
mObject sfObj = new mObject();
sfObj.files = new List<Files>();

for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Files f = new Files();
    f.name = 'my file.txt';
    f.data = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZmlsZQ==';
    f.doctype = 'pdf';

    f.index = new List<Index>();

    for (Integer i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++) {
        Index i1 = new Index();
        i1.name = 'my text index name';
        i1.value = 'text value';

        f.index.add(i1);
    }
    sfObj.files.add(f);
}

JSON.serialize(sfObj);
```

Comment: Thanks @damecek Index can have more than one record. your code will work for one index need to generate payload for multiple index records. I am struggling in adding files to payload using for loop

Comment: i have added for loops

Comment: Tried your code getting Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: mObject. here is my code `public void saveFile(){
        mObject sfObj = new mObject();
        sfObj.files = new List<Files>();// Error here

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Files f = new Files();
            f.name = 'my file.txt';
            f.data = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZmlsZQ==';
            f.doctype = 'pdf';

            f.index = new List<Index>();
.......
            sfObj.files.add(f);
        }
    }`

Comment: yeah, either your class with the mObject is not saved properly, or is like inner class with different namespace.

Comment: you should definitely invest some time in apex trailheads
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro

Comment: Thanks @damecek. It worked. It is inner class. Thanks for your help